# StackOverflowError

Tags: java, объекты, main

```
package graphic.tests.package1;

public class ClassD extends ClassC {
    ClassB b = new ClassD();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB classB = new ClassD();
    }
}
```

данный код выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at graphic.tests.package1.ClassD.<init>(ClassD.java:7)
    at graphic.tests.package1.ClassD.<init>(ClassD.java:7)
    ......................................................
    at graphic.tests.package1.ClassD.<init>(ClassD.java:7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Интересно знать, почему появляется такая ошибка?

во всяком случае напишу, что ClassC наследуется от ClassB.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ClassD extends ClassC {
  ClassB b = new ClassD();
```

В конструкторе объекта типа `ClassD` создается объект типа `ClassD`, в конструкторе которого создается объект типа `ClassD`, в конструкторе которого создается объект типа `ClassD`, ...

*Round and round it goes, where it stops nobody knows.*

Comment: заметил, что что с рекурсией связано (ну с помощью дебаггинг и вашего ответа), но не представил как именно бесконечно продолжается этот процесс.. Решил ClassB b = new ClassD(); переместить в метод main() до обьявления ClassB classB = new ClassD(); проблема исчезнула. Ну я понимаю, что когда создаем обьект чего то,  обязательно идет процесс создания переменных создаваемого обьекта, ну понятно, что через classB вызывается b, но как оттуда снова все повторяется превращаясь в бесконечный цикл - это я не понял

Comment: @RubenKubalyan "через classB вызывается b" - нет, через `new ClassD()` вызывается конструктор `ClassD`, который создает поле `ClassD` объекта `ClassD` и так далее. Когда Вы перенесли строчку в  `main`, Вы убрали член класса, разорвав бесконечную цепочку создания объектов, и объявили локальную переменную.

Comment: заметил, что разорвал бесконечную цепочку, но откуда само бесконечность создалось - я не увидел. Не знаю, возможно, что все уже вы написали в своем комменте, но ....мне не удается пока... не вижу как бесконечность создается.

Comment: вижу как один создал второго, но как второй снова создал первого, который снова второго - не вижу...

Comment: @RubenKubalyan второй создает третьего, третий - четвертого, ...

Comment: допустим, но как?

Comment: @RubenKubalyan `ClassB b = new ClassD();
`

Comment: ладно, просто запомню как аксиому.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi4_uV5O05I