# Некоторые странные моменты связанные с потребностью сделать Нисходящее Приведение (Java)

Tags: java

Мой вопрос написал ниже в комментах программы с достаточно подробным описанием причины возникновения собственно самого вопроса.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

interface Pol{
    void polik();
}

class Polsha implements Pol{
    public void polik(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    public void ohh(){
        System.out.println("ohhh man");
    }
}

public class Test5_plus_2_level {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> t = new PriorityQueue<>();
        t.offer(8);

        t.contains(8); //почему работает без нисходящего приведения???
                       //Queue ведь не содержит метод contains() и сам является
                       //интерфейсом, также как и Pol ниже,
                       //но требования компилятора судя по всему разные. 

        Pol polsha = new Polsha();
        ((Polsha) polsha).ohh();
        polsha.ohh(); //тут понятно почему НЕ работает.
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021509/stackoverflowerror

Comment: Закрыть вопрос пока рано. (речь исключительно о вопросе, ссылку которого вы тут оставили)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

`Queue` наследует метод `contains` от `Collection`

Comment: Вопрос снят. Спасибо.